# How to manipulate the result set of more than one function using node js

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, callback

I have node js files restservice.js and mysql.js

In mysql.js i have two functions as elementlevelpricing and pricingdetail

In restservice.js i have api which has the code as :

var workload = req.body;
var workloadinfo = {
workloadId: workload.workloadId,
        ownerId: workload.ownerId,
        uniqueName: workload.uniqueName,
        name: workload.name 
    }

if(workload.elements && workload.elements.length > 0)
    {

```
    var elementlevelpricingSummary = {};
    var elementArray = [];
    var elementinfo = {};
    var metadataModified = {};
    var pricingDetail = {};


    async.forEachSeries(workload.elements, createResponse, function (err) {
        res.send(workloadinfo); 
    });


    function createResponse(elements,callback) {

        var resourceIdentifierArray = [];

        elementinfo = elements;

        resourceIdentifierArray.push(elements.uri);


        var resourceIdentifiers = resourceIdentifierArray.join(',');


        // Get element level pricing summary
        mysql.elementlevelpricing(resourceIdentifiers, function(result){

                    // do some stuff here

        return callback();

    });
};
};
```

I need to call the function pricingdetail in mysql.js and append the result to global variable workloadinfo (which already should have result set of elementlevelpricing and Can thats what is sent within foreachSeries ). Can anyone suggest me the profession way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asynchronous functions. The whole point of Node.js is to avoid blocking. Blocking in Node.js is worse than blocking in threaded environments, because there aren't any other threads (though there may be other clustered processes). You're blocking the *only* event loop available. That means that your whole server has to wait, doing absolutely no work until your I/O is done.